# Constructing a table from a constraint on another table

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I have a 1000X6 table, where in each row the first three columns are dependent on the second three. I then make smaller tables of 1000X2 from these first three columns and basically `ListPlot` the `τ` s. Here's the code:

```
FullTab1 = Table[{Subscript[τ, extra], Subscript[τ, mix1], 
 Subscript[τ, mix2], u, Subscript[ϕ, 1], Subscript[ϕ, 2]} 
/. {Subscript[ϕ, 2] -> Subscript[ϕ, 1] - u^2/(8 Subscript[ϕ, 1]^2)}
 /. {Subscript[ϕ, 1] -> (RandomReal[{0.5, 1}])*Exp[I*RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}]], 
u -> (RandomReal[{0.001, .1}])*Exp[I*RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}]]}, {i, 1, 1000}]

Smtabext = Table[{Re[FullTab1[[i, 1]]], Im[FullTab1[[i, 1]]]}, {i, 1, 1000}]
Smtabmix1 = Table[{Re[FullTab1[[i, 2]]], Im[FullTab1[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, 1000}]
Smtabmix2 = Table[{Re[FullTab1[[i, 3]]], Im[FullTab1[[i, 3]]]}, {i, 1, 1000}]

ListPlot[Smtabext]
ListPlot[Smtabmix1]
ListPlot[Smtabmix2]
```

So here's the question. The values of the first column of `FullTab1`, i.e. `Subscript[τ, extra]` , should all have imaginary part equal to 1, but not all of them do. I'm only interested in the rows that do satisfy the `Im[#1]=1` condition. I would like to make my '`Smtab`' s only consistent of these rows. Any insight on how this could be done?

I have tried `If, For, Select, Do`, and a few other commands but I'm not sure if I'm using them right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome again to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: As written the first column of `FullTab1` contains only the symbol, `Subscript[\[Tau], extra]`, and no complex numbers, because no values have been assigned to `Subscript[\[Tau], extra]`.

Comment: the \[Tau] 's are complicated functions based on \[Phi]s and u. and they give numerical values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my desired answer. In case anyone needs something similar, I'm posting my code here. If anyone cares to clean it up that would be great because I don't know most shortcut tricks. Here it is:

```
lgt = Length[Select[FullTab1, Im[First[#]] > 0.9 &][[All, 1]]]

ext = Table[{Re[Select[FullTab1, Im[First[#]] > 0.9 &][[j, 1]]], 
   Im[Select[FullTab1, Im[First[#]] > 0.9 &][[j, 1]]]}, {j, lgt}]
mx1 = Table[{Re[Select[FullTab1, Im[First[#]] > 0.9 &][[j, 2]]], 
   Im[Select[FullTab1, Im[First[#]] > 0.9 &][[j, 2]]]}, {j, lgt}]
mx2 = Table[{Re[Select[FullTab1, Im[First[#]] > 0.9 &][[j, 3]]], 
   Im[Select[FullTab1, Im[First[#]] > 0.9 &][[j, 3]]]}, {j, lgt}]

ListPlot[ext]
ListPlot[mx1]
ListPlot[mx2]
```

This only plots the 648 out of 1000 entries of `FullTab1` , were the imaginary part of `First[#1]` is 1. (for some reason ==1 was not working, but since I knew the values were either 1 or 0.5, writing >0.9 works for me.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your self-answer I think you want this:

```
SeedRandom[0]
FullTab1 = RandomComplex[{0 I + 0, 2 I + 2}, {20, 3}];  (* example data *)

sel = Select[FullTab1, Im[First[#]] > 0.9 &];
lgt = Length @ sel;

{ext, mx1, mx2} = Transpose[{Re@sel, Im@sel}, {3, 2, 1}];

ListPlot[ext]
ListPlot[mx1]
ListPlot[mx2]
```

[image]